# Json encode a php mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am having issues with a $json variable in my code. For some reason, my php query isn't being encoded into my $json variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT `$column`, `Year`, `Month` FROM unemployed WHERE year BETWEEN ? AND ? and month= ?";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $gYear, $gYear2, $gMonth);
$stmt->bind_result($Column, $year, $month);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
$json = array();

if ($numRows) { ?>

<table>
<tr>
<th scope="col"> Hi </th>
<th scope="col"> Year </th>
<th scope="col"> Month </th>
</tr>

<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $Column; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $year; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $month; ?> </td>
</tr> 
$json['unemployed'][]= $row;
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php
echo json_encode($json);
var_dump($json);
?>
```

After running this script, there still isn't anything in my $json variable. Does anyone know why that is? Shouldn't the variable now be an array with my query values (each row would now be part of an array)?

Comment: This is what I get: $json['unemployed'][]= $row; $json['unemployed'][]= $row; echo json_encode($json);
var_dump($json);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't even look like

```
$json['unemployed'][]= $row;
```

is within php tags.

Also, it looks like fetch() returns boolean. When you call fetch(), it looks like it fills the variables $Column, $year, and $month with the values from the row. So instead of

```
$json['unemployed'][]= $row;
```

Do this:

```
$json['unemployed'][]= array($Column, $year, $month);
```

Comment: Yes that was previous error. Except now I don't believe what I am getting is correct. Here is what var_dump is now: {"unemployed":[true]}array(1) { ["unemployed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } }

Comment: @user2562125 What output did you expect?

Comment: Something like {"unemployed":[["183,000","1992","January"],["175,000","1993","January"]]}

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php It looks like this function returns True/false

Comment: So what could I use in place of $stmt->fetch?

Comment: @user2562125 So instead of setting $json['unemployment'[] to $row, set it to array($Column, $year, $month)

Comment: array($Column, $year, $month) is what you're looking for to make it similar to the expect output you showed me

Comment: What is all of the stuff behind this? {"unemployed":[["1,682",1991,"January"]]}..... (This code is directly behind what is above) array(1) { ["unemployed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "1,682" [1]=> int(1991) [2]=> string(7) "January" } } }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39290/discussion-between-rkman-and-user2562125)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're outside of the scope of the PHP interpreter when attempting to parse the PHP code.

```
</tr> 
$json['unemployed'][]= $row;
```

to

```
</tr> 
<?php $json['unemployed'][]= $row; ?>
```

Comment: Okay now I am getting this: (var_dump is this) {"unemployed":[true]}array(1) { ["unemployed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) } }